# uploading an image to MySQL from iOS using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I need help and can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I have an app that I want to store an image to MySQL using PHP. here is the code that I am using, I can't see what I am doing wrong...Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://homeWeb.local/postPicSK.php?";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// picture
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
CGFloat compression = 0.5f;

//UIImage *smallSizeImage = [self scaleImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(140.0, 80.0)];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression);

// date and time
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString* dateAndTime = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

//[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"test\"; filename=\"%@ %@.jpg\"\r\n", [self userNameFetch], dateAndTime] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// set request body
[request setHTTPBody:body];

//return and test
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

my PHP file:

```
<?php
$hostusername = "root";
$hostpassword = "root";
$hostname = "127.0.0.1"; 

$courtname = $_POST['name'];
echo "Court Name:".$courtname."<br>";

$image1 = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['name']);
echo $image1;

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $hostusername, $hostpassword) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("scoreKeeper",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select userName");

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO teamData (courtName, liveGameFeedImages)
            VALUES ('$courtname',$image1')");

if($query)
{
   echo"Successful";
} else {
    echo"Error";
}

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I can't get it to post to the database or get anything to echo back

Comment: Storing an image on the database is not a good practice usually.

Comment: My customer wants it that way, otherwise I would have stored it to a file.

Comment: I think you need to recommend to your client why they shouldn't be doing it this way. Show them several use cases with speed, cost and other indicators to convince them. Seriously push it though, I'm sick of finding legacy apps or dealing with business guys that have no clue but read a theoretical article on how to do something and insist on using it because it makes them look as if they know what they're doing/think they want that. Educate educate educate.

Comment: well, I figured out how to do it two ways which I will post below. The first will post it to a folder and the second will post it to a MySQL database. I can see how posting to the database will slow it down after posting many photos. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

its better if you can use AFnetworking for image upload ,

its quite fast and simple

below i am updating the code , please look over that:

```
    NSData *imageDataNew;
    CGFloat compression = 1.0f;
    CGFloat maxCompression = 0.1f;
    int maxFileSize = 250 * 1024;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:THIS.fullPathToFile];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression);
    while ([imageData length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
    {
        compression -= 0.1;
        imageDataNew = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression);
    }
    int random = arc4random() % 9999999;
    NSString *photoName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-Photo.png",random];


    // NSLog(@"new pwd is =%@",passwordTxtF.text);
    AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yoururlname/project/"]];
    [client defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"HMU/broadcast.php?" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
                                    {
                                        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:photoName mimeType:@"image/png"];
                                    }];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
     {
         NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

     }];
    [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {

         NSData *data = (NSData *)responseObject;
         NSError *error;
         NSArray *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
         NSLog(@"dict is %@", dict);
         NSString *message1=[dict valueForKey:@"message"];
         NSLog(@"message=%@",message1);
         NSString *status=[dict valueForKey:@"status"];
         if ([status isEqualToString:@"1"])
         {
              UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"HMU APP!" message:message1 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [alrt show];
         }
         else if ([status isEqualToString:@"0"])
         {
              [hud hide:YES];
             UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"HMU APP!" message:message1 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [alrt show];
             alrt.tag=2;

         }
     }
            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {

     }];
    [operation start];
}
```

enjoy coding :)

Comment: Thank you for your post but I went with an AFNetworking 2.0 solution instead of the 1.x solution you posted. My solution is posted below, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with that seems to work. I hope it can help someone else with the same question.

.m file

```
- (IBAction)post:(id)sender
{

    // filter the comment field
    filteredPostText = [commentTextView.text iod_filteredString];

    // compress image
    CGFloat compression = 1.0f;
    UIImage *image = imageView.image;
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression);

    // create file name
    int random = arc4random() % 9999999;
    NSString *photoName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-Photo.jpg",random];


    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc]     initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://homeWeb.local"]];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"courtName": courtName, @"fileName": photoName};
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"postPicSK.php?" parameters:parameters     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:photoName     mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
    }];
    [op start];
}
```

PHP file to post to a folder

```
<?php
$hostusername = "root";
$hostpassword = "root";
$hostname = "127.0.0.1"; 

$courtname = $_POST['courtName'];
echo "Court Name:".$courtname."<br>";

$filename = $_POST['fileName'];
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
{
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['image']['name'])." has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

PHP file to post to a MySQL database

```
<?php
$hostusername = "root";
$hostpassword = "root";
$hostname = "127.0.0.1"; 

$courtname = $_POST['courtName'];
echo "Court Name:".$courtname."<br>";

$image1 = basename($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
echo "Image:".$image1."<br>";

$tmp_img = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $hostusername, $hostpassword) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
//echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("scoreKeeper",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select userName");

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO teamData (courtName, liveGameFeedImages)
            VALUES ('$courtname','$tmp_img')");

if($query)
{
   echo"Successful";
} else {
    echo"Error";
}

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```